# Move Images to gallery programmatically in Android

Tags: android, image, move

This question may have been asked elsewhere but did not work for me.

I save images in the app-private folder and the user has the option to move it to Android gallery. So my question is how to do that?

This is my code

```
String outPath = "new path which is gallery";
  File outFile = new File(outPath);
  // File (or directory) to be String                                       
sourcePath="image in the app-private folder";
  File file = new File(sourcePath);

   // Destination directory 
    boolean success = file.renameTo(new File(outFile, "name of image"));   
 System.out.println("success: "+success);
```

success here is always "false"